# C/C++/Java Design Question: Keeping Track of Many Variables by Saving To File and Parsing Afterwards

Tags: java, c++, c

Suppose I have a game written in C/C++.  For simplicity, I have:

```
struct masterStruct
{
       Coords player1;
       Weapon player1;
       Gravity player1;
       ...
};
```

Suppose this struct contains 1000s of variables that relate to the player.  I want to be able to create a "snapshot" of the player's state at time t = 10s of my game with all of these variables.  The snapshot should be saved in a fle.

Now, suppose my hard core developing group decided it is necessary to add a 1001th variable to the structure.  Now, my game, expecting there to be 1000 variables fails to load the "snapshot" correctly (because of that last variable).

My question: how do I tackle such a dilemma? Should I create these "snapshots" with version numbers and a handshake between snapshot file and game loader so only approved version files will be loaded?

--------------------- Side Note:
I am using Lua as the scripting language to parse all of these data which is pretty nice.  It's just reading the variables which is a pain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a good serialization library with versioning support.  [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) is a very good library for this sort of thing.

Of specific interest to you should be this feature (quoted from the docs):

> Independent versioning for each class
>   definition. That is, when a class
>   definition changed, older files can
>   still be imported to the new version
>   of the class.

Comment: If I were to read this serialized data in Java, would it be possible? I'm trying to see if it's possible to support C++ and Java